# Can subclipse show history of merged branches

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I want subclipse to show SVN history with all the merge history.  On the command line it would be "svn log -g".  I know you can turn on the option "Include Merged Revisions" but it just shows you the revisions that was merged in and not the details like the comments of the merged in branches.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 'Include Merged Revisions' checked, you should be able to right click a logged commit with merged revisions -> "Show Merged Revisions"

[image: Show merged revisions]